# Centering terms of an equation inside an aligned environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I have the following equation inside an aligned environment:

[image: equation]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\expr}[1]{\delta\Delta\Gamma_{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    X &= \expr{A} + \expr{BC} + \expr{D}\\
    &= \expr{A} + \expr{B} + \expr{C} + \expr{D}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I would like to align the first and second `+` signs on the first line with the first and last `+` signs on the second line. I have used a word processor to show you what I want:

[image: sample]

In other words, the `\expr{BC}` is centered. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

No need to guess a good spacing, because TeX can do the work.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}% first solution
\usepackage{eqparbox}% second solution

%%% for the second solution
\newcommand{\same}[2]{\eqmakebox[#1][c]{$\displaystyle#2$}}
%%%

\newcommand{\expr}[1]{\delta\Delta\Gamma_{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{*{9}{ >{{}}c<{{}} }}
  X &=& \expr{A} &+& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\expr{BC}} &+& \expr{D} \\
    &=& \expr{A} &+& \expr{B} &+& \expr{C}         &+& \expr{D}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  X &= \expr{A} + \same{X}{\expr{BC}}           + \expr{D} \\
    &= \expr{A} + \same{X}{\expr{B} + \expr{C}} + \expr{D}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The `\same` macro for the second solution takes as first argument an arbitrary string of characters that *must* be unique throughout the document for the particular parts you want to have the same width. In other words, if you use the same construction elsewhere, you need to pass something different from `X`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `matrix` or with `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\expr}[1]{\delta\Delta\Gamma_{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\setlength\arraycolsep{0.5pt}
\begin{matrix}
  X & = \expr{A} + &       \expr{BC}     & + \expr{D}\\
    & = \expr{A} + & \expr{B} + \expr{C} & + \expr{D}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\setlength\arraycolsep{0.5pt}
  \begin{array}{crcl}
    X &= \expr{A} + &       \expr{BC}     & + \expr{D}\\
      &= \expr{A} + & \expr{B} + \expr{C} & + \expr{D}
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution based on `eqparbox` (requires two compilations):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\expr}[1]{\delta\Delta\Gamma_{#1}}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{3}
    X &= \expr{A} & & + \eqmakebox[E]{$\expr{BC}$} & & + \expr{D}\\
    &= \expr{A} & & + \eqmakebox[E]{$\expr{B} + \expr{C}$} & & + \expr{D}
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are other very fine solutions, I just want to show an alternative, what I'm using mostly for all my equations (but not seeing very often on this site). `IEEEeqnarray` is an environment from the `IEEEtran` document class, but you can load only the macros with `\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}`. The equation array is a bit more complex at first, but can solve many more complicated alignment situations. That's what I like: A solution that's "fits all".
Here is your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\newcommand{\expr}[1]{\delta\Delta\Gamma_{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCcCcCc}
    X &=& \expr{A} &+&        \expr{BC}     &+& \expr{D} \\
      &=& \expr{A} &+& \expr{B}  + \expr{C} &+& \expr{D}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

`IEEEeqnarray` works by explicitly defining the used columns between alignment points. You can use `r`, `c` and `l` for right, center and left alignment. Their upper case versions additionally apply an operator spacing around the column.
In your example every second column is an operator, thats why I'm using the upper case variant there.

`IEEEeqnarray` is of course a bit more verbose than e.g. `align`, but IMHO that pays out. You can check out the documentation at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetrantools.